# How to install latest version of R on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, r, dell-vostro

I am not able to download the latest R version on my Dell Vostro 14 3000 Series laptop running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I typed in the standard commands on Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install r-base

sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

But the net result is R 2.14.1 getting installed instead of R 3.2.0 (latest version) or even 3.1.1

I'm a Linux / Ubuntu newb, so please do guide keeping that in mind. Cheers!

Comment: See the second answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## GUI method

1. In the Ubuntu Software Center, click "Edit > Software sources..."
2. On the "other software" tab, click "Add..."
3. Enter the following settings:

   - Type: Binary
   - URI: `http://cran.fhcrc.org/bin/linux/ubuntu`
   - Distribution: trusty/
   - Components:
   - Comment: R CRAN

This creates a new "software source" that will be checked alongside the regular Ubuntu/Canonical software repositories. After you do this, you need to re-run `sudo apt-get update` to query the new repository. After that, your system will default to installing R from the CRAN source rather than Canonical, since the CRAN source will always have an equal or greater version number.

### Important notes

- the URI line can have lots of different values, and you should pick one that is geographically close to you from the [list of CRAN mirrors](http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html). `cran.fhcrc.org` is in Seattle, USA.
- the Distribution line should match the "codename" of your Ubuntu version, which you can get by typing `lsb_release -cs` in a terminal window.

## Terminal method

There are good instructions [here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README). Briefly:

```
codename=$(lsb_release -c -s)
echo "deb http://cran.fhcrc.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $codename/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rdev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

Again, replace `cran.fhcrc.org` with a geographically appropriate choice from the [list of CRAN mirrors](http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html).